# Asp.Net Core 2.2 Converting large Cshtml files into Pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf, razor

I want to convert large razor view (over 100000 lines) into PDF.
After converting the view into string, im using SelectPdf nugget as folows.

```
 SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();
 SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString);
 doc.Save("doc.pdf");
 doc.Close();
```

It 'works' but mu document isnt rendered as it should be, it only has 6 pages, the content generated in view by loop

```
<table>
@foreach(var i in Model.Items)
{
    <tr><td>Some data</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

is not fully renderd and everything under is not rendered on the PDF.

**I must use PDF converter that requires html string and works as well in console app as in web api.**

Also, i want to avoid spliting my html string into smaller pieces, generating PDF for every piece and merging them into one document.
Please help.

Comment: Have you ever checked the value of the `htmlstring`,  whether it contains all of the records or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would dump out your HTML before you try and generate the PDF. Make sure it contains what you expect. If it's an issue with SelectPdf and your able to make an API request, check out https://docamatic.com. There is a HTML to PDF endpoint and also a dynamic table template.